# Is it possible that only finitely many Fermat numbers are composite?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, fermat-numbers

The current status of the Fermat numbers $$F_n=2^{2^n}+1$$ where $n$ is a nonnegative integer , is that it is prime for $n\le 4$ and composite for $5\le n\le 32$

It is conjectured that only finitely many Fermat primes exist , the probability of a further Fermat prime is less than $1:10^9$ and the next possible is $F_{33}$.

> It seems therefore absurd that $F_n$ is prime for every sufficiently large $n$ , in other words , that only finite many Fermat numbers are composite. But such proofs are usually out of reach. Is this actually an open problem ? Is it true that we cannot rule out this scenario ?

Comment: Title: Do you mean *finitely many*? And yes, the conjecture seems to be out of reach (but I am not an expert). For possible references see [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Fermat+number) for example.

Comment: @Peter "Many" is an adjective, so the word should be "finitely", which is an adverb (modifies verbs, adjectives, and other adverbs), rather than "finite", which is an adjective (modifies nouns and pronouns).

Comment: @DietrichBurde That the short list of known Fermat primes is already complete is actually an extremely likely scenario. Ironically, Fermat conjectured that ALL Fermat numbers are prime. Euler was the first to disprove this by showing $641\mid F_5$. But as we see , we cannot actually say much about the possibility of further Fermat primes , many of the Fermat numbers are known to be composite, but that's it.

Comment: The current status can be looked up [here](http://www.prothsearch.com/fermat.html) - Interesting is that $F_{20}$ and $F_{24}$ are known to be composite, but no factor is known.

Comment: Fermat was a lawyer and a mathematician, and has made other claims, which are most likely not true (the "margin"),  but I do not mean to diminish him, of course. Concerning your title, no, there are infinitely many composed Fermat numbers. This is what we will prove (hopefully).

Comment: Fun fact : As mentioned in the link, $360$ Fermat numbers are now known to be composite , for every degree of the circle one :) And for numerologists : $360$ has another fun property : The first $360$ digits of $\pi$ after the comma end with "$360$"

Comment: $$(2^{2^n}+1)(2^{2^n}-1)+2= 2^{2^{n+1}}+1$$